# How to Find joint Probability mass function of $P_{AB}(a,b)$ given $P_A(a)$ and $P_B(b)$?

Tags: probability

A Super market orders supplies by fax. Depending on the size of the order, a fax can
be either:

Page for a short order

pages for a long order

The market has three different suppliers:

The cheese supplier is 20 km away.

The chocolate supplier is 100 km away.

The fruits supplier is 300 km away.
An experiment consists of monitoring an order and observing $N$, the number of pages and $D$, the
distance the order is transmitted. The following probability model describes the experiment: 

`╔═══════╦══════╦═════════╦══════╗
║       ║cheese║chocolate║fruits║
╠═══════╬══════╬═════════╬══════╣
║ short ║  0.2 ║   0.2   ║  0.2 ║
║ order ║      ║         ║      ║
╠═══════╬══════╬═════════╬══════╣
║ long  ║  0.1 ║   0.2   ║  0.1 ║
║ order ║      ║         ║      ║
╚═══════╩══════╩═════════╩══════╝`

1. Find $p_{N,D}(n,d)$, the joint PMF of the number of pages and the distance. 
  I can find $P_N(n)= 0.6$ and $0.4$ depend on long or short. and i can find  $P_D(d)$ in similar ways. Now how i can find $p_{N,D}(n,d)=?$. Do i need to find those $P_N(n)$ and $P_D(d)$ ? to find

2. The price per page of sending a fax is 1 cent per kilometer transmitted. $C$ cent is
the price of one fax. What is $E[K]$, the expected price of one fax?

In this question i also need a hint

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first point, you have the probabilities already in your table. The calculations you sketch out are not needed.

Assuming that a short order has 1 page and a long order has $B$ pages.
First, you can calculate the kilometer pages
$$
\begin{array}{lccc}
 & cheese (20 km) & chocolate (100km) & fruits (300 km) \\
short (1 page) & 20 & 100 & 300\\
long (B pages) & 20 B & 100 B & 300 B\\
\end{array}
$$
Now, you can multiply component by component this table with your table and you obtain
$$
\begin{array}{lccc}
 & cheese (20 km) & chocolate (100km) & fruits (300 km) \\
short (1 page) & 4 & 20 & 60\\
long (B pages) & 2 B & 20 B & 30 B\\
\end{array}
$$
Now, you can sum the elements of this table and you obtain 
$$
E[K]=84+52B
$$

Comment: I'm bloody beginner in Probability. Yes short is given 1 and long is given 2. i need to understand that $P_{N,D}(n,d)$ and express it by Big Brace mark if u know what i mean